# Replace contents after specific character using template filter in django

Tags: python, django

I've been trying this for some time now, I want django to replace any "@variable" it finds inside a string with something else.

So for example, if we wanted @ to return the number of characters:

> 'Hello, this is my string. @barbaz knows about it, @foo also knows
>   about it.'

would turn into

> 'Hello, this is my string. 6 knows about it, 3 also knows about it.'

This is what I've tried so far:

```
@register.filter(is_safe=True)
def parse_users(value):
    user_count = range(value.count('@'))

    for count in user_count:
        result = value[value.find('@')+1:value.find(' ')]
        print(result)

    return string
```

but this just prints an empty string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest to use regex here.

```
import re

def parse_users(value):
    usernames = re.findall(r"@\w+", value)
    for username in usernames:
        value = value.replace(username, str(len(username[1:])))
```

value result: *'Hello, this is my string. 6 knows about it, 3 also knows about it.'*

Comment: This literally just returns 1 on every @ no matter the length.

Comment: My bad, I mistakenly wrote username[1:] incorrectly, answer updated.

Answer (score 1):

`value.find(' ')` will return the same thing regardless of `'@'`'s existence in `value`.  You can change it to something like this:

```
for count in user_count:
    from_at = value[value.find('@')+1:]
    result = from_at[:from_at.find(' ')]
    print(result)
```

Comment: It seems that if there is a linebreak right after the '@' it will include `</p></p>SomeOtherContent` Is it possible to have or conditions in the .find method?

Comment: The only way to have `or` conditions in `.find()` is to use a regular expression instead.

Comment: I am really bad with regexes, is it possible to edit your answer with an example?

Comment: @v1k45's answer looks perfect.